# Eiffel: is there a way to prohibit the use of any particularly inherited creation method?

Tags: inheritance, createprocess, eiffel

As `default_create` is always a an example of creation method which can be used for instance creation as `create some_instance` if I don't want to allow the descendants of a class to use it as a creation method is there a way to do that?

### A

```
deferred class A
feature
   make (a_db_connection: DB_CONNECTION)
      do
          default_create
          db_connection := a_db_connection
      end
```

### B

```
class B
inherit
    A
create
    make
    -- default_create -- I'd be able to do that and want to avoid it
```

Answer (score 0):

As soon as a procedure is not listed as a creation one, it cannot be used to create an object. In the original example an instance of the class `B` can created using `make`, but not `default_create`, i.e. the creation instruction `create b` would be flagged as an error (assuming that `b` has type `B`).

On the other hand, if there is no `create` clause at all, and the class is not deferred, then the procedure `default_create` is used to create an object. This can be prohibited by having an empty creation clause:

```
class C
inherit
    A
create -- There are no creation procedures, no instance of the class can be created.
feature
    ...
end
```

Summary:

1. No creation clause: `default_create` is used.
2. Empty creation clause: no instance can be created.
3. Non-empty creation clause: only listed procedures can be used for creation.

Comment: Thx, what I tried to point out is that if the class A wants to forget the default_create procedure and avoid its use you can restrict its use as client with {NONE} exporting but not avoid its use as creation method from any descendant? am I clearer like that? I don't want any descendant to be able to use the default_create as creation procedure is it possible or is it part of the idea that a descendant inherits from the behaviour of its parents @ "any" mean?

Comment: @Pipo There is no such a notion as “private” method, field, etc. in Eiffel. All features from a parent are inherited by a child and can be used.

Comment: As I thought, as us, we have to deal with inherited behaviors ;-)